# Swift - Sorting core data in sections

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've managed to sort the data received from my core data alphabetically, and now I want put the usernames in sections for each letter. I understand that the easiest way to do this is by using NSFetchedResultsController, but I can't figure out how to use this (very few tutorials covering Swift).

So my code looks like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Message")
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Message", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Message")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "username", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    myList = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [Model]

    tv.reloadData()    
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return myList.count
}
```

I was hoping someone could shed some light over the NSFetchedResultsController and help me get on my way.

If I'm not completely wrong, the initialization looks something like this, although I can't figure out the "cache name":

```
let resultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: myList, sectionNameKeyPath: "username", cacheName: <#String?#>)
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the [NSFetchedResultsController class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchedResultsController/initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:) which describes the `cacheName` parameter? Which part of that did not make sense?

Comment: @TomHarrington This actually isn't a simple answer at all. It involves transient core data, NSManagedObject subclassing, and then finally using the NSFetchedResultsController...and no cache necessary. I'm considering writing up an answer, but it would be reeaaally long...

Comment: What is "transient" Core Data?

Comment: @TomHarrington It's a type of non-standard persistent core data attribute which would be used to create a temporary and dynamic "username initial" property in the core data for use in the NSFetchedResultsController. Info available throughout this Apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html

Comment: Oh, transient properties

Comment: @TomHarrington I understand what it means to use a cache file, but I do not understand where to create one for use in xcode.

Comment: @TomHarrington In other words, what type of file do I need to add to use it as a cache-file, and do I need to add any code to this file?

Comment: @frank21 still haven't read the documentation, eh? It would save you a lot of time and trouble.

Comment: @TomHarrington I have and I'm sorry but it didn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up the fetched results controller easily by copying and tweaking the code from the Xcode template. (Create a new project, Master-Detail, check "Use Core Data", copy from MasterViewController.)

The following is not the ideal solution, but I think it is appropriate for your level of experience. When you add the `username` attribute to the `Message` entity object, also add another attribute with the first letter. Then use the *name* of this new attribute as the `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter when creating the fetched results controller.

Don't worry too much about the cache parameter. You can just put any string there, such as `"Root"`, or even pass `nil` to not use cache which is also fine in most use cases.